# Private scope in locally-defined class

Tags: c++

Here's a small example that demonstrates my question:

```
class Foo {
private:
  int x;
  void y() {
    class Bar {
    public:
      Bar(Foo* foo) {
        foo->x = 3;
      }
    };
    Bar bar(this);
  }
};
```

Class `Foo`, and a class defined inside its member function `y` tries to access its private member `x`. Is this allowed?

Visual Studio 2013 can compile this, but IntelliSense seems to think that the private members cannot be accessed and does not list them when typing `foo->` inside the embedded class methods.

Comment: you can directly access th x member of the same instance but since you are passing it a reference to the foo class the intelli-trace persumes that you can send some reference other than its own.

Comment: @UsamaZafar: it would never know whether its the same object or not at compile-time, and it shouldn't matter for scope rules. I'm guessing its just an intelli-sense bug, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is valid.

N4140 [class.access]/2:

> A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class has access. A local class of a member
>   function may access the same names that the member function itself may access.